# Unsure about our current setup + routing issues (Diagram attached)

Tags: network

I work for a medium sized company, we have around 52 computers. The company grew quite a few times meaning switches were bought and attached to meet the demand of new employees/machines.

To sumarize, we have two different ISP, they connect to our LAN with a Routerboard that acts as a load balancer (failover worked best for us) and as a firewall, we then have 4 switches interconected, diagram bellow:
[image: Network Diagram]

- Both routers/board, server and first switch on the same room, next two switches on same rack (in another floor), and the last also in another floor/room.
- The number in the switch represents the ammount of connected computers (roughly).
- Entire network is gigabit.
- Ideally every computer would be able to see each other.

One issue we're still having for as long as I could remember is the managed switch randomly only getting 100MB/s connection to our server (Internet connection is fine, I use iperf to test internaly). Today I noticed that the green wire port which connect both switches (they're in the same rack) is displaying 100MB/s only.

I'm going to crimp a new cable to replace green right now, but I'd like to know, how I can improve our network, if possible. (and how stop all server network from the managed switch going thru green, instead of yellow)

Comment: Welcome to Network Engineering!  In order to be on topic, your equipment manufacturer must provide paid support.  Unfortunately MicrotiK does not.  You can try asking this question on [su].  It also sounds like you have cabling problems.  If all 8 wires in the cable are not connected, you speed will drop to 100M.

Answer (score 1):

From the diagram, your network has grown convoluted. You should redesign with a clear structure (collapsed core, hierarchical two-tier):

- designate one of the switches as *core*
- connect all central services to *core*: firewall, servers, etc - currently there are multiple connections between the server and various switches which might make sense technically, but quickly become a nightmare logically
- if you need to connect end users (access layer) to *core* make a clean division between *core* ports and *access* ports, e.g. 1-10:core, 11-24: access
- connect *access* switches to *core*
- for redundancy, designate a *secondary core* and connect like *core*
- a *secondary core* requires RSTP/MSTP on all switches - use *core* as root bridge with prio 0/0 and *secondary core* as fallback with prio 1/4096
- configure additional RSTP/MSTP settings, depending on your gear (portfast, admin-edge, ...)

> the managed switch randomly only getting 100MB/s connection to our server

That's an issue with the physical layer = port config or cable. Make sure your interconnection patch cables are 100% OK - in doubt, swap them out.

> I'm going to crimp a new cable to replace green right now

Please don't. Use fabricated patch cables only as you can't really get a good, reliable quality using DIY cables (properly testing a self-made cable is far more expensive than buying one).

Note that for a device to be on topic here, the vendor needs to offer optional, paid support, which Mikrotik sadly don't.

Answer (score 1):

I fully second the above answer - this network could use a redesign and proper hierarchy. Considering small scale of this network you would probably be okay with:

- a **set** of core switches, don't rely on one. If that device failed your network is toast. If you can get devices that stack it's the best as I assume the likes of MLAG would be way beyond the budget. If stacking is not an option then edge class devices which run spanning-tree should do
- this set should have get connected to whatever is working as a firewall and redundantly to your server
- from the core, connect your edge switches that will provide networks to the end users. It doesn't matter that much if they are all on the same VLAN or different given the low numbers. If routing on core is configured all devices should see each other
- as for the issues with your server, I have seen plenty of cases where auto-negotiation fails between devices of different vendors. Setting the speed
  statically both ends could be the answer. Zac67 suggested wisely to check the cables as this could be the reason. Going with manufactured cables rather than DIY is a better option in terms of quality in nearly all cases.

Comment: *plenty of cases where auto-negotiation fails between devices of different vendors* - that must have been literally decades ago. Cisco ceased shipping devices implementing their interpretation of Auto Negotiation in 1999. I haven't seen that problem since and current best practice is to leave Autoneg active at all times - it's even mandatory for 1000BASE-T onwards.

Comment: Totally agreed, if I didn't run into it with one ISP last week and a handful of legacy servers in a hospital I used to work for. Totally agreed, auto-negotiation is the default best practice. I tend to fall back into static only if all other reasonable venue fails.